# Disable / Remove rename functionality from everywhere in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am being using Eclipse for almost all my projects. Now I have a requirement, where-in I need to disable the rename functionality on the file menu, and also remove the refactor->rename option and also these changes must reflect in target platform.

Could you please give me a solution for this? I tried couple of things like : Windows -> Preference -> refactor etc etc. but this doesn't solve my entire problem, rename still works on target platform. My main need is to remove rename functionality from target platform, be it through file menu, project explorer, or F2.